# Extract files from disk raw image

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, filesystems, disk-image, binary-files

I have two raw images of some old IDE HDD (one made without of any data correction and second made with). Trying to mount the images to the system by various methods do not work properly.

I use Windows software named `UltraISO` or try to boot from this image in `VirtualBox` (entire drive was bootable) and every time I get an errors on every image. I know that some HDD sectors was bad, so some bytes in this images have a wrong values. May be this is the main reason of those errors in software.

Is there any working way to fix wrong bytes or to extract all dirs and files from the raw disk image as is? Linux disk mount rises the error too (I mount image as `loop0p1` device and trying `testdisk` util that do not see correct partitions).

Comment: "Linux disk mount rises the error too" -- What exact commands did you use? What was the error exactly? Is the image supposed to have a partition table? Are you able to read the partition table? Does the partition table make sense?

Comment: I edit my question, thank you.

Comment: How *exactly* do you "mount image as `loop0p1`"? I'm asking because `loop0p1` *already looks like* the first partition of `loop0`, so trying to find partitions *inside `loop0p1`* makes no sense.

Comment: using Kali diskmount

Comment: _"Trying to mount the images to the system by various methods do not work properly."_ - do not work **how**? _"every time I get an errors on every image"_ - what errors? _"Linux disk mount rises the error too"_ - what error? We can't read your mind - we don't know what you're doing and seeing, therefore we can't tell if you're doing it right or what could be wrong.

Comment: What does `gdisk -l /path/to/the_image_as_regular_file` print?

Comment: I get the right result with `testdisk <file>`, thank you all very much! But my image has on it 10 directories that are all with corrupted data and I didn't see what in that directories, and also deep search of testdisk does not help me, so I recovered only 1 dir and a few useful files.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two raw images of some old IDE HDD (one made without of any data correction and second made with).

I doubt that. The combination of your statement above combined with the fact that you raise a pretty simple question does not fit together.

Apart from CDs and DVDs and maybe Bluray there is no software available for you that will provide you with data which is even below read and write operations on sector level. (containing raw sector information).

> Is there any working way to fix wrong bytes or to extract all dirs and files from the raw disk image as is?

No. There is no guaranteed way to recover deleted or broken data.
What can be done is only a way of sophisticated guessing by software or by a skilled human. Sometimes it works, other times it fails.
Anyway your question is already answered on Superuser in articles about data recovery.
If the answer to your question was "Yes" why bother with backups?!